# Foxit Reader, highlight text that is read by text-to-speech feature

Tags: pdf-reader, foxit-reader, text-to-speech

I use Foxit Reader to have my documents read for me by using

- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+B</kbd> to start reading
- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd> to pause reading
- <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+E</kbd> to end reading

I was wondering if there is an option that highlights the current word that is read. Because sometimes you do not understand a word that is read for you and you want to read it.